# Rounds integer even with float- python

Tags: python

Below is my code. the issue is in MAIN. The code works as a person trying to buy items into a cart and you can see the total price of those items. They have to enter in the price for each item that they want. If a person inputs a number to two decimal places, it rounds it to the nearest whole number.

```py
import locale

class CashRegister:
    def __init__(self):
        mself.items = 0
        self.price = int(float(0.00))
  
    
    def addItems(self,price): #keeps track of total number of items in cart
        self.price += price
        self.items += 1
        print(self.price)
    
    def getTotal(self):  #returns total price
        return self.price
  
    def getCount(self):  #return the item count of the cart
        return self.items
  
    def clearCart(self):  #clears cart for another user or checkout
        self.items = 0
        self.price = int(float(0.00))

  def main(): 
      user_name = input('What is your name?\n') #weclomes user
      print("Hello",user_name)
      locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
      user_name = CashRegister()  #user is using the cash register
      while True:
        line = input ("Would you like to add another food item to your cart? Choose y or n \n") 
        if line  == "y":
**          price = int(float(input("please input the price of the item\n")))
          print(price)**
          user_name.addItems(price)   #user adds prices to cart
        elif line == "n":
          print("Your total checkout price:", locale.currency(user_name.getTotal()) )
          # int(float(locale.currency(user_name.getTotal())))
          print("Your total item count", user_name.getCount())
          user_name.clearCart() #clears cart for another user/checkout
          break
        else:
            print("Error")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

As soon as the person inputs the number, I printed it to see if that's where the problems lies. I'll enter `3.20` but it automatically converts it to 3. I have no idea how to force it to keep those decimals. I even tried printing it with the `int/float` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you call `int()` if you want decimal places? Just call `float()` as you do.

Comment: "I'll enter 3.20 but it automatically converts it to 3" - Yes, that's what int() does.

Comment: Integers do not have decimal places.  I'm very confused as to what you even want.

Comment: The code you have posted does not make sense and cannot be run because it is not indented properly.

Answer (score 3):

The `int()` function always returns an *integer*. An integer *never* has any decimal points. So use only

```
float(input("please input the price of the item\n"))
```

instead of

```
int(float(input("please input the price of the item\n")))
```